# Less with Symfony and Assetic. Permissions for node_modules so I don't need sudo?

Tags: node.js, symfony, less, npm, assetic

I am trying to get less installed properly to run with Symfony and Assetic. I have a permissions issue. This is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How do I set permissions so that I can run app/console assetic:dump without needing sudo?

I've installed less using

sudo npm install -g less

node_modules gets installed in /usr/lib/node_modules

user "nobody" is the owner of /usr/lib/node_modules/less
group is my user group.

I have set node, node_paths and apply_to in my config.yml.

It works fine from a browser in the Symfony dev environment. My less files are happily being compiled into css.

If I run app/console assetic:dump it says "Cannot find module 'less'". It took me a while to discover that it's a permissions problem. It works if I run sudo assetic:dump.

It seems wrong to run app/console with sudo. Do I need to change ownership of /usr/lib/node_modules? Everything seems to have world and group read access .

I don't understand how Apache manages to run it okay under www-data.

Comment: Well ... it seems to be working just fine without sudo this morning. The only real change is that I shut it down over night so it has had a reboot. Maybe I should delete this question.

Comment: Restart solved my problem also...

Answer (score 0):

```
chown $(id -un):$(id -Gn | cut -d' ' -f1) /usr/lib/node_modules
```

with this you won't need to install using sudo ever again.

#### Explanation

1. `id -un` is the same as `whoami` it prints your username in the terminal
2. `id -Gn` print the groups you are in separated by spaces.
3. `id -Gn | cut -d' ' -f1` -> this part takes the first group
4. `chown [username]:[group] [filename]` changes the owner of the file

So basically you change the owner from **root** user to yourself.

#### Downside and Workaround

Other users on your mac will not be able to modify this file since you own it. 
But you can also let them by setting permissions for the group

```
chmod 775 /usr/lib/node_modules
```